# A fatal scripting error occurred. Variable is not defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

When I run this query in SQLCMD mode in SSMS 2017 and SQL Server DB. It works fine.

```
--SQLCMD mode
--DECLARE Global variables
:SETVAR daysBack  -1
SELECT $(daysBack)
```

Result: -1

If I run only 1 line

```
SELECT $(daysBack)
```

in the same window on the same connection, or in another tab. I am getting error

fatal scripting error occurred.
Variable daysBack is not defined.

Why I am getting error?

and how can I make my varibale Global, for example like

```
SELECT '$(COMPUTERNAME)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. SQLCMD variables are a client tool trick, they don't really exist as a SQL Server concept.

The connection and server are not aware of their existence and the system doesn't persist knowledge of variables used in previous batches when you submit a new batch.

From [sqlcmd - Use with Scripting Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-2017):

> If more than one type of variable has the same name, the variable with the highest precedence is used.
>
> 1. System level environmental variables
> 2. User level environmental variables
> 3. Command shell (SET X=Y) set at command prompt before starting sqlcmd
> 4. sqlcmd-v X=Y
> 5. :Setvar X Y

Of these, the first three are effectively taken from when a particular process was launched, unless that process has specific tooling to allow environmental variable to be edited. Neither SSMS nor SQLCMD has such functionality so you cannot create a variable in these categories once the tool is already running.

The fourth is SQLCMD specific and has no equivalent in SSMS. Only the last one (using `:setvar`) remains, and this does not create a "global" variable (which are in fact just the environmental variables and the SQLCMD built-in variables).

Comment: $(COMPUTERNAME) is shared for all queries.

Comment: @justromagod - `$(COMPUTERNAME)` is accessing the `COMPUTERNAME` environmental variable. Environmental variables need to be set before launching a client tool and are fixed during its execution. There's no way from within an SSMS window to change or create new environmental variables.